# Hosting Powershell modules in a network location?

Tags: powershell

I'm working in an organization on different projects, and I'd like to maintain my own Powershell toolbox with helper functions, classes, etc. It can all be in one Powershell file as far as I concern.

But I don't want to copy this file around on dozens of different machines and git repositories. Is there to consume a Powershell file from a location like Artifactory or something like this?

Comment: [Yes, you can map a network share location as a PowerShell repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-local-psrepositories?view=powershell-7.1#registering-a-local-repository)

Comment: One option is simply `Import-Module '\\path\to\toolbox.ps1'`. Even for complex modules with multiple files, this works fine.